# Missing or unused dependency array in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When implementing the hook code from here

https://blog.logrocket.com/patterns-for-data-fetching-in-react-981ced7e5c56/

I get the following warning, what does this actually mean?

./src/components/Users.tsx
  Line 20:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'data.users'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. You can also replace multiple useState variables with useReducer if 'setData' needs the current value of 'data.users'  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
const USER_SERVICE_URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

export function List() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({ users: [], isFetching: false });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUsers = async () => {
      try {
        setData({ users: data.users, isFetching: true });
        const response = await axios.get(USER_SERVICE_URL);
        setData({ users: response.data, isFetching: false });
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        setData({ users: data.users, isFetching: false });
      }
    };
    fetchUsers();
  }, []);

  console.log(data)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix missing dependency warning when using useEffect React Hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook)

Comment: No, the function is already declared inside use effect, so according to that post I should'nt be seeing this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that since you use `data.users` in the code inside the `useEffect` block, and you've define an empty dependencies array, `data.users` might be stale.

To solve that problem use the `setState` [updater function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates). Which allows you to use the previous state, while creating the new one:

```
    setData(data => ({ users: data.users, isFetching: true }));
```

Or

```
    setData(data => ({ users: data.users, isFetching: false }));
```

Another options is to create a simple reducer, that will work like `setState()`, but will override changed items, and not the entire state:

```
const reducer = (state, payload) => ({ ...state, ...payload });

export function List() {
  const [data, setData] = useReducer(reducer, { users: [], isFetching: false });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUsers = async () => {
      try {
        setData({ isFetching: true });
        const response = await axios.get(USER_SERVICE_URL);
        setData({ users: response.data, isFetching: false });
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        setData({ isFetching: false });
      }
    };
    fetchUsers();
  }, []);

  console.log(data)
```